# C language: Releasing memory of pointers to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

Say I have declared a pointer to a struct and assign it with malloc() using this definition

```
typedef struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;
```

Then somewhere in the code I declared two pointers to it

```
NODE *node1, *node2 = NULL;

node1 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
node2 = node1;
```

My question, should I use "free()" to release node2 just like people always do to node1 via *free(node1)*. What's exactly the effect of the assignment *node2 = node1;*

Thanks.

Comment: node1 _is_ node2. Just free one of them not both or it will crash.

Comment: `free` just knows about the address. It doesn't know what variables you have and doesn't care which points to which memory address

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. So what u saying is I can also free node1 via free(node2), no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
node1 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

you have something like

```
+-------+      +-----------------------------+
| node1 | ---> | memory for a NODE structure |
+-------+      +-----------------------------+
```

After the assignment `node2 = node1` you have instead this:

```
+-------+
| node1 | -\
+-------+   \    +-----------------------------+
             >-> | memory for a NODE structure |
+-------+   /    +-----------------------------+
| node2 | -/
+-------+
```

In other words you have *two* pointers pointing to the *same* memory.

Attempting to call `free` using either of the two pointer variable will invalidate *both* pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You release neither `node1` nor `node2`. You release the memory they point to.

With that in mind, it should become clear why you should only call `free` once

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the address returned by `malloc()` and family to `free()` in-order to free the allocated memory.

In your case you are just assigning the returned address to some other pointer and using that in free which is fine.

You shouldn't do

```
node2 = node1;
node2 = node2 +1;

free(node2);
```

So you can use one of them in your case to free the memory

`free(node1)` and `free(node2)` are same in your case

Comment: @JamesReal Yes you can use one of them

Answer (score 1):

`node1` is a pointer, meaning the value of it is the virtual memory address of the allocated struct.

Assigning `node2 = node1` just copies that address.

As a result `free(node1)` and `free(node2)` are equivalent.